# How do I use Sprockets with Sinatra without a rackup file?

Tags: sinatra, rack, sprockets

I'm writing a library that has an embedded Sinatra app launched via Thor. I want to mount instances of `Sprockets::Environment` at `/css` and `/js` and have the main app mapped to `/`. This would be easy using `Rack::URLMap` in a `config.ru` file, but in this case there isn't one because I'm starting the Sinatra app programmatically with `Sinatra::Application.run!`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing it by writing a custom middleware with some of the functionality from `Rack::URLMap`. It looks roughly like this:

```
require "sprockets"
require "sinatra/base"

class SprocketsMiddleware
  attr_reader :app, :prefix, :sprockets

  def initialize(app, prefix)
    @app = app
    @prefix = prefix
    @sprockets = Sprockets::Environment.new

    yield sprockets if block_given?
  end

  def call(env)
    path_info = env["PATH_INFO"]
    if path_info =~ prefix
      env["PATH_INFO"].sub!(prefix, "")
      sprockets.call(env)
    else
      app.call(env)
    end
  ensure
    env["PATH_INFO"] = path_info
  end
end

class App < Sinatra::Base
  use SprocketsMiddleware, %r{/assets} do |env|
    env.append_path "assets/css"
    env.append_path "assets/js"
  end
end

App.run!
```

Answer (score 13):

Actually, this is not that hard. All you need to do is assign an instance of `Sprockets::Environment` to a Sinatra configuration variable and define some paths to look up the assets you're interested in.

Here's a basic example:

```ruby
require "sass"
require "haml"
require "erubis"
require "sinatra"
require "sprockets"

set :assets, Sprockets::Environment.new

# Configure sprockets
settings.assets.append_path "app/javascripts"
settings.assets.append_path "app/stylesheets"

# For compressed JS and CSS output
require "yui/compressor"
settings.assets.js_compressor  = YUI::JavaScriptCompressor.new
settings.assets.css_compressor = YUI::CssCompressor.new

get "/" do
  haml :index
end

get "/javascripts/:file.js" do
  content_type "application/javascript"
  settings.assets["#{params[:file]}.js"]
end

get "/stylesheets/:file.css" do
  content_type "text/css"
  settings.assets["#{params[:file]}.css"]
end
```

Happy sprocketing!

Comment: This, like all the sinatra-sprockets examples I've seen, does not work (or, no longer works). Has something in sprockets changed?

Comment: @Ian This answer was appropriate in 2012, but a lot has changed in both Sinatra and Sprockets since then.

FWIW, Sinatra now seems to have an index of common needs (this being one of them). Check out their recommended usage of Sprockets and see if that works out for you: http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/asset_management/sprockets

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I integrated Sprockets into Sinatra with Rails-like directory layout, helpers and minification for JS and CSS.

I chose to write a Sinatra extension. This extension encapsulates the configuration of sprockets (paths, minification, helpers) and can be registered by the application.

```rb
module Sinatra
  module Assets
    extend Sinatra::Extension

    configure do
      set :assets, Sprockets::Environment.new(root).tap { |assets|
        %w(assets vendor/assets).each do |base|
          %w(images javascripts stylesheets).each do |type|
            assets.append_path File.join(base, type)
          end
        end
        if production?
          assets.js_compressor = Closure::Compiler.new
          assets.css_compressor = YUI::CssCompressor.new
          uid = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.dirname(__FILE__))[0,8]
          assets.cache = Sprockets::Cache::FileStore.new("/tmp/sinatra-#{uid}")
        else
          assets.cache = nil
        end
      }
    end

    get "/assets/*" do
      env["PATH_INFO"].sub!(%r{^/assets}, "")
      expires Time.now + (365*24*60*60) if settings.production?
      settings.assets.call(env)
    end

    helpers do
      include Sprockets::Helpers

      Sprockets::Helpers.configure do |config|
        config.expand = development?
        config.digest = production?
      end

      def assets_environment
        settings.assets
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Using the extension in your application is simple:

```rb
class App < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Assets
  # ...
end
```

Assets can be placed in `assets`, or `vendor/assets`. For example `vendor/assets/jquery.js` can be referenced by logical name, i.e. `http://localhost/assets/jquery.js`.

In the example above I'm using [sprockets-helpers](https://github.com/petebrowne/sprockets-helpers) which provides helpers such as `javascript_tag`. The configuration given above assumes that in development, you want to expand assets required by the referenced asset (resulting in multiple tags per asset).